# Can I restrict a contenteditable td to only allow numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to restrict one column or single tds to only accept numbers.
Is this even possible. I only find something to inputs.

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="notfallTable">
  <tr>
    <th value="name">Name</th>
    <th>Nachname</th>
    <th>Nummer</th>
    <th>Abteilung</th>
    <th id="thCheckbox"><button id="checkAll" class="btn btn-success">Check all</button>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$.getJSON("NotfallSMS.json", function(data) {
  var items = [];
  var checkbox = "test";
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push("<tr>");
    items.push("<td contenteditable>" + val.Name + "</td>");
    items.push("<td contenteditable>" + val.Nachname + "</td>");
    items.push("<td contenteditable>" + val.Nummer + "</td>");
    items.push("<td contenteditable>" + val.Abteilung + "</td>")
    items.push("<td class='check'><input class='check' type='checkbox'>" + "" + "</input></td>");
    items.push("</tr>");
  });

  $("<tbody/>", {
    html: items.join("")
  }).appendTo("table");
});
```

Comment: Java !== JavaScript

Comment: The code you've found relating to `input` elements will also work for `contenteditable`. Do you have a specific issue with it?

Comment: @Andreas JavaScripting == [Java Scripting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/)?

Comment: Also note that `input` elements don't need a closing `</input>`

Comment: I didnt know that i can use the code relating to input. Thank you . I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I have one function for this.

HTML

```
<input type="text" placeholder="number" onblur="OnlyNumber(event,false)" OnlyNumber="return SadeceRakam(event);">`
```

Jquery

```
 function OnlyNumber(e, allowedchars) {
                var key = e.charCode == undefined ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
                if ((/^[0-9]+$/.test(String.fromCharCode(key))) || key == 0 || isPassKey(key, allowedchars)) { return true; }
                else { return false; }
            }
```